# Get Custom taxonomy parent with wordpress REST API

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I have a custom taxonomy `product_category` , and it accepts parent / child relationship.

The url: `/wp-json/wp/v2/product_category` shows me everything, Parent and Child.

is it possible to add parameters to show only parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution  :

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/product_category/?parent=0
```